# Binding a usercontrol to SQL datatable

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datatable

I have a user control that is supposed to view some data from a SQL datatable. My database class is called DBManager it has a property called ResTable which is of type Datatable. It has data that is relevant to what is in my user control. Upon retrieval of the Table i want to instantiate a number of controls as the number of rows in the Datatable and bind each field with the corresponding one in the table. I know how to bind comboboxes but not usercontrols.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Menupedia"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="Menupedia.RestaurantViewer"
x:Name="UserControl"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Width="330" Height="150">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="330">
    <Label x:Name="label_Name" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="16,0,0,7" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="72" FontFamily="Public Enemy NF" FontSize="14.667" Foreground="#FFEF7B54"/>
    <Image x:Name="image_Logo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,13,0,37" Width="100"/>
    <Label x:Name="label_Phone" Margin="0,61,122,59" FontFamily="Public Enemy NF" FontSize="14.667" Foreground="#FFEF7B54" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="42" Content="{Binding Hotline}"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="combobox_Branch" Height="30" Margin="0,21,29,0" Style="{DynamicResource MPComboBox}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="135"/>
    <Image Margin="126,55,0,59" Source="Images/Phone.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="36"/>
    <Image Margin="120,13,164,0" Source="Images/Branch.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="label_labelCuisines" Content="Cuisine:" Height="30" Margin="125,0,150,25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Public Enemy NF" FontSize="14.667" Foreground="#FFEF7B54"/>
    <Label x:Name="label_Cuisines" Height="48" Margin="0,0,29,7" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Public Enemy NF" FontSize="14.667" Foreground="#FFEF7B54" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="117"/>
</Grid>
```

The corresponding object of this usercontrol has no properties. I though have a class called Restaurant that have the same format as that of the Datatable i am using but i don't know how to fill it either.

Answer (score 0):

You can make constructor of the user control take in parameters. You can then bind the controls of user controls to the passed parameters. Example:

```
 public partial class TestControl : UserControl
 {
    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public TestControl(string name)
    {
        lblName.Content = name;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
```

Use it as:

```
TestControl tc = new TestControl("Austin");
```